# How to say "It's not a lie if you believe in it" in Japanese

Tags: words, set-phrases

Eijiro doesn't have the definition so I thought I'd ask here

Comment: Please check the meta discussion “[Should pure translation questions be allowed?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76/should-pure-translation-questions-be-allowed)”

Comment: @Oleg. Considering that you have enough reputation to access the chat site, [do join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage). Our chat function handles this kind of requests better.

Comment: I didnt realize that that's what i should use. Will do it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a lie if you believe it.

> [信]{しん}じれば[嘘]{うそ}じゃない。

[Here](http://asagi-0015.at.webry.info/201010/article_18.html) is an article using the expression (the first result when you Google the above translation).